# How do I create an array of SDL_Surface items?

Tags: c++, sdl

Basically I have my SDL_Surfaces in different variables such as:

```
SDL_Surface *interface = NULL;
SDL_Surface *background = NULL;
```

It would be useful for me to have them in a single array, something like:

```
SDL_Surface *images[2];
images[0] = load_image("assets/tiles/interface.png");
images[1] = load_image("assets/tiles/background .png");
```

How can I do this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Besides some differences from my personal style, your code looks correct.  Why do you think something is wrong with it?

Comment: I have been testing this for a while, it seems it works fine as a global variable, but once inside a class it's inaccessible either publicly or privatly. Can't figure out why

Comment: Could you show us the class declaration and how you are accessing it? Also I assume it is a compile time error rather than run time?